# Can multiple foreign keys point to the same primary key in MySql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that logs a user's id and user's name. I want to create a second table that creates a group of different users such that the table columns look like: groupname, user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, user6. I want to reference the user columns (1-6) as a foreign key to the first table's user id column as a primary key. I am using phpMyAdmin on a local server. Can this be accomplished?

EDIT:

A user shouldn't be able to belong to multiple groups, and I was thinking I could set the referenced user columns as null until a user joins the group at which point the primary-key user_id would load into the referenced user_id columns.

Comment: Can one user belong to multiple groups?

Comment: ^ No only one user can belong to a single group at a time

Comment: Then use the primary key of the group as a foreign key in the user table.

Comment: Why don't you just create one column that deals with user_id and make it a one to many relationship? By asking this question it should make you think over about the schema of your table

Comment: @MauricioTrajano It's the other way around. Add a column `group_id` to the `user` table.

Comment: Im so confused by this is it a group, and then each column is a user_id for a user that belongs to the group?

Comment: @MauricioTrajano Yes that was what I was trying to accomplish. Since there would be a maximum of 6 users per group, each user_id column would be set to null until a user joined the group. Is this a practical way to accomplish this task?

Comment: @Yonny Just model it a normal one-to-many relation. The design you're proposing doesn't make sense. It's unwieldy, impractical and doesn't scale. Adding more than 6 members to a group is impossible, and any operation involving group members would require querying on all columns.

Comment: just add the group_id as an attribute to user_table as @RobbyCornelissen suggested

Comment: if you want to add a 7th group member you're going to run into trouble

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Ok that makes sense and then just set the group_id to null if a user hasn't joined a group yet? Also would this work if users are constantly creating new groups?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Alright thanks! Also would this still work if users are constantly creating new groups?

Comment: Yup. No problem as long as users cannot belong to multiple groups.